# java why with general imports not compiling

Tags: java, path, writer

I wrote a program that writes a line to a file. When I use more general imports, it doesn't compile while with these imports it works:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

public class IOtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ELiz\\Desktop\\Lcode\\tests\\filetest\\Maryhad.txt");

        String s = "Mary had a little lamb.";

        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset)) {
            writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles no problem in my command line, I'm running windows 7 and jdk 8.
But when I use:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class IOtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ELiz\\Desktop\\Lcode\\tests\\filetest\\Maryhad.txt");

        String s = "Mary had a little lamb.";

        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset)) {
            writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the errors:

```
IOtest2.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
        ^
  symbol:   class Charset
  location: class IOtest2
IOtest2.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
                          ^
  symbol:   variable Charset
  location: class IOtest2
IOtest2.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ELiz\\Desktop\\Lcode\\tests\\filetes
t\\Maryhad.txt");
        ^
  symbol:   class Path
  location: class IOtest2
IOtest2.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ELiz\\Desktop\\Lcode\\tests\\filetes
t\\Maryhad.txt");
                    ^
  symbol:   variable Paths
  location: class IOtest2
IOtest2.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset)) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable Files
  location: class IOtest2
5 errors
```

I'm trying to understand why one set of imports worked when compiling when the other didn't. Classes Files, Paths, Path, and Charset are all part of the java.nio package, why didn't they import? Is there a shorter import version I could use?

Comment: they part of `import java.nio.file.*;` not `import java.nio.*;`

Comment: Ok, so I can only import packages with the .*; extension for certain packages.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hierarchy in Java packages.

```
java.nio.charset
```

is not a "subpackage" of

```
java.nio
```

so importing `java.nio.*` doesn't import `java.nio.charset.*`.

If you want to import everything in the `java.nio.charset` package as well as everything in the `java.nio` package, you have to wildcard import both:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
```

---

Note that wildcard imports (or "on-demand imports", as they are called in the language spec) aren't particularly useful. They obscure where a particular name in the source file is imported from, making it hard to understand the code. Indeed, some style guides (e.g. [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3.1-wildcard-imports)) forbid wildcard imports entirely.

Any IDE worth its salt can insert the (non-wildcard) imports automatically; for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> in Eclipse "organizes imports". If you're not using an IDE, you're just making your life unnecessarily hard.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to add

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```

The wildcard "*" only makes the classes in this package visible, not any of the subpackages.

this also means that to import `java.nio.charset.Charset;` you need to add:

```
import java.nio.charset.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your assumptions are incorrect. subpackages will not going to get imported as part of the wild card '*' import, only classes do.

Hence, in your case it will be :

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import java.nio.* because Charset (ex.) is not a classes of its own. Use wildcard for classes in the same level of packages and not for subpackages.